# Редактировать тему VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

как в VS Code подкорректировать атрибуты служебных слов, напрмер для языка С. У меня сейчас тип класса идет bold и italic. Хочу убрать bold. У меня установлена тема Dark Modern. И где вообще хранится файл этой темы? Раньше помню был онлайн редактор еше во времена SublimeText, вот как здесь https://habr.com/ru/articles/172973/ можно через него можно было это сделать, но сейчас и его нет.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes